# MySQL Add/Grant user if it does not exist

Tags: mysql, users, permissions

I am trying to create a update/install script that adds a user and database only if it's a fresh install. The script uses a randomly generated password for the user, so using the `GRANT` statement as suggested in [a StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357760/mysql-create-user-if-not-exists) will not work.

- Is there a way to create, set password, and grant privs a user *only* if it does not exist?
- Am I going to have to run a check in the script and then run the statement or can I build it into a SQL file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is Dynamic SQL

```
SET @sql_found='SELECT 1 INTO @x';
SET @sql_fresh='GRANT ALL ON *.* TO randomuser@''%'' IDENTIFIED BY ''randompassword''';
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @found_count FROM mysql.user WHERE user='randomuser' AND host='%';
SET @sql=IF(@found_count=1,@sql_found,@sql_fresh);
PREPARE s FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

If `@found_count` is 1, then `SELECT 1 INTO @x;` will execute. (this query does nothing)

Otherwise, `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO randomuser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'randompassword';`

**Give it a Try !!!**

Answer (score 0):

You can write a stored procedure to verify if it doesn't exist and add it:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UserVer`(
    IN eUser VARCHAR(50),
    IN ePass VARCHAR(50),
    IN eHost VARCHAR(50),
    IN eDataBase VARCHAR(50))
sp_np:BEGIN
    /*  | Variable Declaration | */
        DECLARE vUser VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE vPass VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE vHost VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE vDataBase VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE vReg INT(8) DEFAULT 0;
    /*  | Variable Asignation | */
        SET vUser       =eUser;
        SET vPass       =ePass;
        SET vHost       =eHost;
        SET vDataBase   =eDataBase;
    /*  | WorkPlace |   */
    SET vReg=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysql.user WHERE User=vUser AND Host=vHost);
    IF (vReg=0) THEN # If Exists EXECUTE
        #SET @DROP_USER=CONCAT(" DROP USER ","'",vUser,"'@'",vHost,"';");
        SET @CREATE_USER=CONCAT("CREATE USER ","'",vUser,"'@'",vHost,"'"," IDENTIFIED BY '",vPass,"';");
        SET @GPRIVILEGES=CONCAT(" GRANT ALL ON ",vDataBase,".* TO '",vUser,"'@'",vHost,"';");
        #PREPARE DROPUSER FROM @DROP_USER; EXECUTE DROPUSER; DEALLOCATE PREPARE DROPUSER;
        PREPARE CREATE_USER FROM @CREATE_USER; EXECUTE CREATE_USER; DEALLOCATE PREPARE CREATE_USER;
        PREPARE GPRIVILEGES FROM @GPRIVILEGES; EXECUTE GPRIVILEGES; DEALLOCATE PREPARE GPRIVILEGES;
        LEAVE sp_np;
    ELSE
        SELECT '01' AS sERROR,'User exists.' AS sDESC_ERROR;
        LEAVE sp_np;
    END IF;
    END
```

And you'll call it like this:

```
CALL UserVer(
    'testUser', #eUser VARCHAR(50),
    'TestPwd', #ePass VARCHAR(50),
    '%', #eHost VARCHAR(50),
    'PRUEBA'); #eDataBase VARCHAR(50))
```

Result:

[image]

It will prompt a `sERROR` with **01** as value and `sDESC_ERROR`.